# Knockout js subscribe behaves differently

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using subscribe in my application I use three subscribe the first two works good but the last observable that I add subscribe doesn't work as I want.

```
  // Listen to likelihood so that everytime it change it will also change the RiskLevel
        self.Likelihood.subscribe(function (newValue) {               
            self.RiskLevelName(GetRiskLevel(newValue, self.Consequence()));
        });
        self.Consequence.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            self.RiskLevelName(GetRiskLevel(self.Likelihood(), newValue));
        });
```

When I change the Likelihood or the Consequence it change the value of the RiskLevelName it's working great. I add a breakpoint in the

```
 self.RiskLevelName(GetRiskLevel(newValue, self.Consequence()));
```

I noticed that it didn't heat the breakpoint when I change the value of Likelihood. The funny thing is that it change the value of self.RiskLevelName.

I add another code to subscribe to the Account but it's not working.  I didn't  get any error in the console

```
       self.Account.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            console.log(newValue);
        });
```

Here is the way I bind them to my DOM elements

```
 <div class="span6">
          <div class="control-group" id="likelihoodModalControlGroup">
                   <label class="control">Likelihood</label>
                   <div class="controls">
                         <select id="likelihood" class="input-large custom" data-bind="value:Likelihood, options:$root.LikelihoodList, optionsValue:'Key', optionsText:'Value', optionsCaption:'Select Likelihood'">
                                    <option value="0">Select Likelihood</option>
                           </select>
                      </div>
             </div>
   </div>
   <div class="span6">
             <div class="control-group" id="consequenceModalControlGroup">
                     <label class="controls">Consequence</label>
                     <div class="controls">
                         <select id="consequence" class="input-large custom" data-bind="value:Consequence, options:$root.ConsequenceList, optionsValue:'Key', optionsText:'Value', optionsCaption:'Select Consequence'">
                             <option value="0">Select Consequence</option>
                          </select>
                     </div>
               </div>
   </div>

  <div class="span6">
      <div class="control-group" id="AccountModalControlGroup" >
           <label>Account</label>
           <div class="controls">                                   
                    <select class="input-large custom"  data-bind="value:Account, options:$root.ProjectList, optionsValue:'Key', optionsText:'Value', optionsCaption:'Select Account'">
                          <option value="0">Select Account</option>
                     </select>                                   
             </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you maybe post a JSFiddle with your code (or a simplified version which still demonstrates your problem)? Because your code should just work.

Comment: Second @nemesv. I was [trying to repro](http://jsfiddle.net/spuU4/) but I can't. If the "Account" dropdown list is changed it is logged in the console as expected.

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle Code http://jsfiddle.net/ramon26cruz/k2Bza/

Comment: Finally I solved my problem.. The reason why the .subscribe is not working because the dropdownlist that was bind to my Account has a optionsCaption. I'll just remove it and it's now working

Comment: The behavior you describe certainly isn't documented; create a minimal test case and if it duplicates the behavior, file a bug report.